# Salesforce Org to Org Object migration

Tags: salesforce

I have developer edition, I am new to salesforce started moving the objects from org to org and I'm not sure what is the best way to do that I have read few sites but does not really help and I have downloaded Eclipse and also Force.IDE

any pointers or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ant migration tool.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

I'm not usually a huge fan of Salesforce's documentation, but I think this one actually covers what you need to know.